# Implement vitess with magento 2

Tags: mysql, magento2, vitess

Can someone please help me on how to implement a vitess with Magneto 2 Ecommerce platform?
I want to do sharding Magento 2 database in the community version.

Comment: Please provide some of you existing code and specific questions.

Comment: I am new to vitess so i want to use vitess with magento 2. is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely you'll be able to achieve this for two reasons:

1. Although an application does not *generally* need to be vitess-aware, certain queries that magento may issue may not be supported e.g. joining on a sub-query. Other things that aren't supported are auto-incrementing ids
2. In order to get the most from Vitess, you need to supply it with a VSchema - a json definition of your schema detailing how each table should be sharded 9plus other stuff).  If you don't supply this, vitess just won't work